# How Can I send between sockets kivy.properties.ObjectProperty?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, filesystemobject, object-property

I need to send over sockets this object and can't find a way to do it (pickle doesn't work here, can't also convert this object to bytes)

```
ObjectProperty(FileSystemLocal(), baseclass=FileSystemAbstract)
```

This is FileSystemLocal:

```
class FileSystemLocal(FileSystemAbstract):
'''Implementation of :class:`FileSystemAbstract` for local files.

.. versionadded:: 1.8.0
'''

def listdir(self, fn):
    return listdir(fn)

def getsize(self, fn):
    return getsize(fn)

def is_hidden(self, fn):
    if platform == 'win':
        if not _have_win32file:
            return False
        try:
            return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
        except error:
            # This error can occurred when a file is already accessed by
            # someone else. So don't return to True, because we have lot
            # of chances to not being able to do anything with it.
            Logger.exception('unable to access to <%s>' % fn)
            return True

    return basename(fn).startswith('.')

def is_dir(self, fn):
    return isdir(fn)
```

Comment: So...what is a FileSystemLocal? Why do you need to send it over a socket? Depending on what it is, maybe you can just serialise it manually.

Comment: added above FileSystemLocal class. I'm creating a cloud client-server project using kivy file chooser class. the file chooser class collects data from FileSystemLocal Object

Comment: It sounds like you should just manually serialise the data you need.

Comment: what do you mean by that? I need the whole object

Comment: You undoubtedly don't "need" the whole object, just some of its data, and it may be easier to send that than to resolve the pickling problem. If you do want to resolve the pickling, I think you can define more manually how the object should be handled, but I'm not that familiar with it so I can't comment more.